# How can I add my custom component to Mui Theme options so that I can override it?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I've been messing with this for a bit and I keep running into type errors, so there must be something that I'm missing.

What I want to do is create my own component and then be able to override some styles within the components section of a Theme. From what I've read, I need to add the component to the Components interface, which allows me to add that Custom component to the `components` section in `ThemeOptions`, but I can't find anything that describes how to add either `styleOverrides` or custom props like `root` or `bottom` so that I can pull those out and apply the styles to the component.

```
// module aug
declare module '@mui/material/styles'{
   interface Components {MyComponent?:type of MyComponent}
}
// my component
type MyComponentProps = {prop1:string, prop2:string, styleOverrides?:{bottom:CSSProperties}
const MyComponent = ({prop1:string, props2:string}:MyComponentprops) => { return <> ... </> }
// theme options
const options = {components:MyComponent:{styleOverrides:{bottom:{color:'red'}}}}
```

I get an error that the `type {styleOverrides?:bottom:{color:string} } is not comparable to {prop1:string, prop2:string, styleOverrides}:MyComponentProps. type {styleOverrides?:bottom:{color:string}} provides no match for the signature {prop1:string, prop2:string, styleOverrides}:MyComponentProps):Element`

I've tried several different ways of formatting the props for the component, but the styleOverrides always comes back empty.

What am I doing wrong here?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In your module augmentation example you have `interface Components {MyComponent?:type of MyComponent}`, but you need to define the full structure of the type that would occur within `MyComponent` in the theme. This means you need to specify the full structure of the `defaultProps` key and the `styleOverrides` key (also `variants` if you want to support that concept, but I don't bother with variants in my example). You can see [here](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/blob/v5.12.1/packages/mui-material/src/styles/components.d.ts#L6) how MUI defines this for each of its components.

The `defaultProps` key can have the same type as the props for your component (`MyComponentProps` in my example).

The `styleOverrides` key is quite a bit more complicated. You can see [here](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/blob/v5.12.1/packages/mui-material/src/styles/overrides.d.ts#L133) how MUI defines this for components and my example re-uses MUI's `OverridesStyleRules` type. The main "input" into the generics for that type is the allowed class keys. My example defines that in the type `MyComponentClassKey`. To model off of the MUI approach, typically you would define a "root" class key for the outermost component, and then additional keys for any elements nested within that (e.g. "bottom" in my example).

The next step is to leverage the `defaultProps` and `styleOverrides` from the theme in your component. You can see [here](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/blob/v5.12.1/packages/mui-material/src/Alert/Alert.js#L140) how MUI uses `useThemeProps` to support default props and my example uses the same approach. To support the style overrides, you use the `styled` API passing the second options argument indicating the component name, the slot (i.e. which CSS class key), and the `overridesResolver` which determines which portions of the style overrides are applicable for the slot (and it can potentially take props/state into account if dealing with variants). You can see examples of this within MUI [here](https://github.com/mui/material-ui/blob/v5.12.1/packages/mui-material/src/Alert/Alert.js#L98).

Below is a full working example:

```
import * as React from "react";
import {
  createTheme,
  ThemeProvider,
  Theme,
  styled,
  useThemeProps
} from "@mui/material/styles";
import { OverridesStyleRules } from "@mui/material/styles/overrides";

interface MyComponentProps {
  greetee?: string;
}
type MyComponentClassKey = "root" | "bottom";

const MyComponentRoot = styled("div", {
  name: "MyComponent",
  slot: "Root",
  overridesResolver: (props, styles) => styles.root
})(({ theme }) => {
  return {
    padding: 8
  };
});

const MyComponentBottom = styled("div", {
  name: "MyComponent",
  slot: "Bottom",
  overridesResolver: (props, styles) => styles.bottom
})(({ theme }) => {
  return {
    borderBottom: "1px solid black"
  };
});

const MyComponent = React.forwardRef(function MyComponent(
  inProps: MyComponentProps,
  ref
) {
  const props = useThemeProps({ props: inProps, name: "MyComponent" });
  const { greetee } = props;
  return (
    <MyComponentRoot>
      Hello {greetee}
      <MyComponentBottom />
    </MyComponentRoot>
  );
});

declare module "@mui/material/styles" {
  interface Components {
    MyComponent?: {
      defaultProps?: MyComponentProps;
      styleOverrides?: Partial<
        OverridesStyleRules<MyComponentClassKey, "MyComponent", Theme>
      >;
    };
  }
}

const theme = createTheme({
  components: {
    MyComponent: {
      defaultProps: {
        greetee: "World!"
      },
      styleOverrides: {
        root: {
          backgroundColor: "green",
          padding: 16
        },
        bottom: {
          borderColor: "purple"
        }
      }
    }
  }
});

export default function CustomStyles() {
  return (
    <ThemeProvider theme={theme}>
      <MyComponent />
    </ThemeProvider>
  );
}
```

[image: Edit custom component with styleOverrides support]

Comment: This is awesome! Thank you! Is it possible to use styled with a MUI box rather than a div or does that complicate things more? I'm just curious how one would also specify the `component` that they might want to use dynamically - 'div', 'section' etc.

Comment: It would be possible, but the TypeScript for components like Box that have a `component` prop is quite complicated.

Comment: Also, do I not need to use  he `ComponentNameToClassKey` interface in the augmentation?

Comment: `ComponentNameToClassKey` is a mapping of all the MUI component names to the type for their class key. For MUI it provides a less error prone way to define the types that leverage those pieces rather than dealing with each component individually, but for one component it is simpler to deal with it individually as in my example.

Comment: I think I mostly understand how this is working now. The only things that are hazy are how I would be able to target other component properties within the ones above. For instance, if I had another styled component `{name:'ChildThing`, slot:'Root'}` and it was a child of `MyComponent.Root`, how would I be able to target it in styleOverrides.variant? Is there a way to add props or would I need to target the classname with CSS? If this is out of scope, I can create a new question.

Comment: I think a new question would be useful so that you have the space to more fully explain (with code excerpts and a code sandbox) the additional problem you are trying to solve.

Comment: In case you're [interested.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76130396/using-mui-how-can-i-build-my-components-so-that-i-can-target-child-component-pr) No pressure :D

Answer (score 0):

If 'variant' is needed, try this

```
import { Interpolation } from "@mui/system";

declare module "@mui/material/styles" {
  interface Components {
    MyComponent?: {
      defaultProps?: MyComponentProps;
      styleOverrides?: Partial<
        OverridesStyleRules<MyComponentClassKey, "MyComponent", Theme>
      >;
      variants?: Array<{
        props: Partial<MyComponentProps>,
        style: Interpolation<{ theme: Theme }>
      }>;
    };
  }
}
```