# Using MUI, how can I build my components so that I can target child component props/styles from components.styleOverrides?

Tags: reactjs, typescript, material-ui

I'm trying to build my components so that they are more customizable and more easily overridden through ThemeOptions using slots, but I've hit a couple of snags, especially when trying to target child components - kind of how MUI does some of their own components. How would I go about that?

More questions, comments, thoughts are in the code comments below.

```
// class keys
type ParentKey = "root" | "content"
type ChildKey = "root"
// component props
type ParentComponentProps = {
    variant?:"variant1"|"variant2"
    someProp?:string,
    anotherProp?:string,
}
type ChildComponentProps = {
    prop1?:string,
    prop2?:string
}

// module augmentation
declare module "@mui/material/styles" {
    interface Components {
        ParentComponent?:{
            defaultProps?:ParentComponentProps
            styleOverrides?:Partial<OverridesStyleRules<ParentKey,"ParentComponent",Theme>>
        },
        ChildComponent?:{
            defaultProps?:ChildComponentProps
            styleOverrides?:Partial<OverridesStyleRules<ChildKey, "ChildComponent",Theme>>
        }
    }
}

const ParentComponent = styled('div',{
    name:'ParentComponent',
    slot:'Root',
    overridesResolver:({variant}:ParentComponentProps, styles) => [
        styles.root,
        variant === "variant1" && styles.variant1,
        variant === "variant2" && styles.variant2,
    ]
})<ParentComponentProps>(({theme})=>{
    return {
        // ... base styles for parent root component
    }
})

const ChildComponent = styled('div', {
    name:'ChildComponent',
    slot:'Root',
    overridesResolver:(prop, styles) => styles.root
})<ChildComponentProps>(({theme})=>{
    return {
        // ... base styles for child component root
    }
})

// implementation
const SomeComponent = (props) => {

    const componentProps = useThemeProps({name:'ParentComponent', props})
    const {someProp, anotherProp} = componentProps

    return (
        <ParentComponent>
            {/* I can pass props to ChildCompnent here, but I'd rather do it from the ThemeOptions */}
            {/*
                I'm also not really sure if I can get the child component
                props the same way I got the parent since they wouldn't be in props
                unless I had a prop on the parent that would then get passed like `childProps:ChildComponentProps`
            */}
            <ChildComponent />
        </ParentComponent>
    )
}


// theme options
const options:Partial<ThemeOptions> = {
    components:{
        ChildComponent: {
            defaultProps: {
                // set defaults for ChildComponent Globally
                prop1:'something'
            },
            styleOverrides: {
                root:{
                    // global root overrides for ChildComponent
                }
            }
        },
        parentComponent: {
            defaultProps: {
                // set global defaults for ParentComponent
            },
            styleOverrides:{
                root: {
                    // set root overrides
                },
                variant1:{
                    // overrides for variant1
                },
                variant2: {
                    // overrides for variant2
                    /**
                     * looking for something like this
                     * so that I can override ChildComponent
                     * only for this variant when a child of ParentComponent
                     */
                    ChildComponent: {
                        defaultProps:{
                            prop1: "something else"
                        },
                        root: {
                            // override root styles
                        }
                    },
                    /**
                     * I know this works, but it seems cumbersome
                     * and I can't set the default props for it, but
                     * maybe it's the best way?
                     */
                    "& [class$='ChildComponent-root']":{
                        // overrides styles
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```