# Possible To Theme A Custom Component In MUI?

Tags: reactjs, material-ui

In MUI, you can customize the style of a component through the theme object, as [documented here](https://mui.com/material-ui/customization/theme-components/#theme-style-overrides):

```
const theme = createTheme({
  components: {
    // Name of the component
    MuiButton: {
      styleOverrides: {
        // Name of the slot
        root: {
          // Some CSS
          fontSize: '1rem',
        },
      },
    },
  },
});
```

Can we do that with a custom component?

Let's say specifically that I want to customize the DialogTitle ([see Dialog docs here](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-dialog/)) so that we add a "x" close button, like in [this example](https://mui.com/material-ui/react-dialog/#customization). In that example, you can see they're adding styles directly to the `<IconButton />` by using the `sx` property inline. But what I want to do is pull those styles out into the theme object. Do I need to register the name of the component somehow? It would be great if I could add it to the theme like how you add out-of-box components. So if we called our custom DialogTitle "MyDialogTitle", then it would look something like:

```
const theme = createTheme({
  components: {
    // Name of the component
    MyDialogTitle: {
      styleOverrides: {
        root: {
          // styles here
        },
      },
    },
  },
});
```

Comment: This may be helpful for you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76095729/how-can-i-add-my-custom-component-to-mui-theme-options-so-that-i-can-override-it